# Оптимизация скрипта

Tags: php, синтаксический-анализ

Доброго времени суток! У меня есть скрипт, который парсит много страниц. Причем некоторые страницы приходится грузить через curl. И работает он очень медленно - нельзя ли как нибудь его оптимизировать?

Comment: Можно- надо все переписать на Си.  
А вообще черные ящики трудно поддаются оптимизации.

Comment: ага, а если на ассемблере - то вообще летать будет)

Comment: Намек не понят видимо :) [Чёрный ящик](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D1%91%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%8F%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%BA)  
Как можно говорить об оптимизации не видя кода?  
Могу еще посоветовать скриптовый парсер заменить на регулярные выражения- один нативный вызов регулярного выражения лучше кучи строк скрипта с кучей скриптовых вызовов.

Comment: кода 500< строк, не могу же я весь выложить. на счет регулярок - я simple_html_dom использую

Comment: Очень рекомендую ознакомится со статьей [Сравнение библиотек для парсинга][1], по выводам simple_html_dom самая тормозная, причем сильно.


  [1]: http://habrahabr.ru/post/114323/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Во-первых, пропустите свою программу через профайлер. Например, **xdebug**. Вы должны сразу увидеть, какие вызовы занимают больше всего времени. Их и оптимизируете.

Во-вторых, если вам нужно выдергивать всего несколько значений, я рекомендую использовать *регулярные выражения*. Однако при усложнении структуры парсера от них придётся отказаться.

В третьих, советую посмотреть на *специальные библиотеки*, которые занимаются парсингом. Например, существует несколько библиотек для *PHP*, которые разбирают HTML документы в DOM и работают довольно быстро.

В четвертых, можно использовать **акселераторы** для *PHP*. Они иногда значительно ускоряют обработку скрипта. С их списком можно ознакомиться, например, [тут](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_PHP_accelerators).

Ну и в последних, если всё выше перечисленное не вариант, вам придётся пересаживаться на более быстрый и близкий к машине язык, вроде **С**.

Подробнее ничего сказать нельзя, не видя реализации и результата работы профайлера.

Comment: >вам придётся пересаживаться на более быстрый и близкий к машине язык, вроде С.

@khaos, мне вполне хватает перла, при том, что "много" - это сотни тысяч сраниц :) Не нужно бежать впереди паровоза, вполне может и оказаться так, что основное время тратится не на парсинг, а на скачивание страниц. Например, хорошо ускоряет процесс передача (и обработка) gzip в Accept-Encoding, обработка Last-Modified тоже полезна etc.

Comment: @klopp, вполне вероятно. Мне это тоже немного странно. Но без профайлера (или ручного выяснения временных интервалов), лучше ничего сказать нельзя.